# How to label features in QGIS using SQL statement?

Tags: qgis, labeling, sql

In QGIS, I can't seem to find a way to define the features that I want to label using a SQL query?  Is this possible?

For example, I downloaded the OSM Natural shapefiles, and a lot of those features have no values in their "name" field.  I would like to display all features, but only label those features where `NAME <> ""`.  The same concept could be applied to roads, where `TYPE = "Motorway"`.

In the image below, I want all polygons visible, but don't want to label the 3 polys on the right.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the text 'Label' from "Default Label" option in labeling dialog.

(Or use new labeling.)

There is no SQL for labels yet (but you don't need it in this case).

Comment: Well, that was pretty obvious solution for my immediate needs of removing the default "Label".  Are there any plans for SQL based labeling in the future?  And where can I find the "new labeling" you mentioned (I am using v1.6)?

Comment: 'Labeling' tool is located in 'Attributes toolbar' in 1.6 (icon reads 'ABC')

Comment: I couldn't find a ticket for this feature. You might want to file an enhancement request at http://trac.osgeo.org/qgis

Answer (score 8):

You can now label features using an expression in version 1.8, something like this:

```
CASE WHEN NOT "NAME" IS NULL THEN "Name" END
```

or

```
CASE WHEN "TYPE" = 'Motorway' THEN "Name" END
```

[image: Expression labels]

Comment: Ignore the `Expression is invaild` that is because I don't have those columns in layer

Answer (score 0):

You can select the option in Labels Properties and only label 'selected features'

Comment: While that is a neat tool that can be used much like a "tool tip", it doesn't really work in my scenario because I don't want to label a selection set, but rather the whole data layer, just without certain characteristics.  With "selected features" turned on, it will reset the labels with each change in the selection.